# Android, new support lib 25, BottomNavigationView implementation

Tags: android, android-support-library

As support lib ver 25 released, google produced new `BottomNavigationView` as new API:

> android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView class implements the bottom navigation pattern from the Material Design spec.

Sadly, this doesn't seem true and there is no real documentation. Apparently, the `BottomNavigationView`:

1. Doesn't work as described using `xmlns:design="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android.support.design"`
2. Doesn't support different tab colors or the nice circular reveal color effect
3. Doesn't offer any coordinator layout behavior for automatic hiding
4. Doesn't work with snackbars or FAB
5. Doesn't work with a transparent navigation bar
6. Doesn't mention for tablets

[image]

How can I implement this in the project? And also how to style it to make it actually implement the Bottom Navigation pattern?

Comment: I'm wonder why should you give me **negative** with no reply!!! what a dirty world :|

Comment: Wondering the same. The new BottomNavigationView does not offer any documentation and simply sucks anyway.

Comment: I think you made an interesting question, and the answer provided by Velikodniy is really useful to anyone who wants to implement this new BottonNavigationView. The current documentation doesn't show how to implement it.

Comment: It doesn't resolve your questions but it is a basic implementation : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/7565/the-bottomnavigationview#t=201610210701438958082

Answer (score 5):

Add to your activity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...>

    ...

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

describe menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="add" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="delete" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
        android:title="call" />
</menu>
```

and then you can set listeners:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // ...
        return true;
    }
});
```

You can get more information here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: Thanks, how about the combination with FAB? And also handling `Snackbar` upon it?

Comment: In `Snackbar` constructor you should provide layout to show it with first argument. If you want to show it behind `BottomNavigationView` try to call Snackbar with link to FrameLayout.

Comment: The documentation shows the following way to add the menu items design instead of app:menu.

Answer (score 1):

It's late reply but below solution will save someone's time.please check below points as well.

1. Bottomnavigationview support from version 25+.
2. Update your SDK to latest version.
3. Set project target sdk version to 25.
4. Set below configuration in apps build.gradle.

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'`

Comment: Your theory is wrong that BottomNavigationView supports from Api 25+, because it tested in Kitkat  Api 19 and its working fine